# Custom Logger in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, logging, sails.js, winston, papertrail-app

Below is my log.js file but it only logs "Hello from colorized winston", but it's not logging all my sails.log.info in my app.  What am I doing wrong.  I searched everywhere and can't figure it out.  All I found is this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/67u7SqzsNJQ and it seems to confirm I'm doing correctly.

```
var winston = require('winston'),
  Papertrail = require('winston-papertrail').Papertrail;

var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new Papertrail({
      host: 'logs3.papertrailapp.com',
      port: xxxxx, // my port here
      colorize: true
    })
  ]
});

logger.info('Hello from colorized winston', logger);

module.exports = {
  log: {
    custom: logger
  }
};
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

PS. I'm jumping into a project created by someone else so it's possible they broke something. If someone can give me a lead how to debug by telling me how custom works that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've setup the correct logging level. In your `config/log.js` file, set the log level to something like `level: silly`. This should log pretty much everything.

Comment: I see in my console after doing sails lift that there are things being logged as sails.log.info.  I can try this but don't see why it should make a difference.